# What is the reason for SQLITE UPSERT performance improvement with UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE?

Tags: sqlite

What is the reason for `SQLITE UPSERT` performance improvment with `UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE`?

In **Test #1**, we have a

```
CREATE TABLE FREQMARY(
VALUE CHAR(40),NUMERICVALUE FLOAT, DATETIMEVALUE CHAR(40), COUNT INT, LENGTH INT)
```

and a

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_MARY ON FREQMARY(VALUE).
```

In **Test #1**, we use the following UPSERT:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO FREQMARY(Value, NumericValue, DateTimeValue, Count, Length) 
VALUES ('Braintree Road',NULL,NULL, COALESCE((SELECT Count+1 FROM FREQMARY WHERE Value='Braintree Road'), 1),14)
```

---

In **Test #2**, 
we have a

```
CREATE TABLE FREQMARY(
VALUE CHAR(40) UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE ,NUMERICVALUE FLOAT, DATETIMEVALUE CHAR(40), COUNT INT, LENGTH INT)
```

---

In **Test #2**, we use the same `UPSERT` as **Test#1**,

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO FREQMARY(Value, NumericValue, DateTimeValue, Count, Length) 
VALUES ('Braintree Road',NULL,NULL, COALESCE((SELECT Count+1 FROM FREQMARY WHERE Value='Braintree Road'), 1),14)
```

---

With 1,500,000 UPSERTS wrapped by BEGIN TRANSACTION and END TRANSACTION every 100000 UPSERTS, Test #1 takes 10 hours to complete.
With 1,500,000 UPSERTS wrapped by BEGIN TRANSACTION and END TRANSACTION every 100000 
UPSERTS, Test #2 takes 18 minutes to complete.

May I ask what the reason for `SQLITE UPSERT` **huge** performance improvment with  `UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE`?

Comment: I'm confused by your use of `FREQMARY` in your `INSERT OR REPLACE` statements when the table you create and create an index for is named `TESTMARY`. Did you actually run the test exactly as you describe? Did the table contain any other rows? Did you run the exact same `INSERT OR REPLACE` statement 1.5M times?

Comment: @Omnifarious, FREQMARY is the name of the SQLITE table. May I askwhat the reason for the confusion by my use of FREQMARY in my INSERT or REPLACE. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Omnifarious, I did not run the same exact same INSERT or REPLACE statemnet 1.5 million times.I understand your drift. You are hinting to me that the SQLITE is caching my SQLITE UPSERT results. THank you for reply.

Comment: @Frank - The confusion is because you create a table named `TESTMARY` and then update a table named `FREQMARY`. I'm also confused as to why you post every single reply twice. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The sqlite-users.org experts just answered the question why CREATE TABLE UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE is much faster than CREATE UNIQUE INDEX.

Check whether OR REPLACE part actually works in the second case -
whether Count gets incremented as expected. I suspect that, with ON
CONFLICT IGNORE clause, conflicts may in fact be ignored. Then it works

### much faster simply because it makes much fewer writes.

Igor Tandetnik

Comment: Could anyone tell me if I replace COALESCE with ISNULL in the subselect in the UPSERT: INSERT OR REPLACE INTO FREQMARY(Value, NumericValue, DateTimeValue, Count, Length) VALUES ('Braintree Road',NULL,NULL, COALESCE((SELECT Count+1 FROM FREQMARY ), 1), 14)? THank you for your help.